# Getting Multiple inputs in a form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I wish to get 10 numbers for which i can get mean /median. I have written the logic for computing in a Dll Library. But i don't know how to get multiple inputs using forms in front end. Is there any function like `get()` or `Readline()` (which we generally use in console) that I can use?

Comment: Have single TextBox, With Button, On each Button click parse the `textbox.Text` to integer, Add it to a list and when list's count reaches 10, send the list to your method.

Comment: You can see here - http://www.dotnetperls.com/textbox to start with.

Comment: Not entirely sure how you want the form to work.  There are many ways to get 10 numbers from a form.  Have you tried creating 10 TextBox controls?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to handle this.

The first is a single textbox that will take input from the user in the form of 1,2,3 or comma delimited text.  This will allow you to perform a split to work with the values.

The second method is probably cleaner and easier for the user.  Use 10 textboxes to get the values one at a time.  Then process the input from each textbox individually.

Either way you'll use textboxname.Text to get the value which you can then pass to int.Parse() to turn it into an integer.